# Solving and checking the answer of a first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:
Solve the following differential equations.
$$ x \frac{dy}{dx} + y = y^{-2} $$
Answer:
To solve this equation, we reduce it to a linear differential equation with the substitution $v = y^3$.
\begin{align*}
xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + y^3 &= 1 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} &= 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
3xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 3y^3 &= 3 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} + 3v &= 3 \\
\end{align*}
Now we have a first order linear differential equation. To solve it, we use the integrating factor $I = e^{\int P(x)}$. In
this case, we have $P(x) = 3$.
\begin{align*}
I(x) &= e^{3x} \\
e^{3x} \frac{dv}{dx} + 3e^{3x}v &= 3e^{3x} \\
D\left(  e^{3x}v \right)  &= 3e^{3x} \\
e^{3x}v &= e^{3x} + C \\
v &= 1 + e^{-3x} \\
y^3 &= 1 + e^{-3x}
\end{align*}
Now to check my answer.
\begin{align*}
3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} &= -3Ce^{-3x} \\
y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} &= -Ce^{-3x} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -Ce^{-3x} y^{-2} \\
x \frac{dy}{dx} + y &= x \left(  -Ce^{-3x} y^{-2} \right)  +  \left( 1 + e^{-3x} \right)^{\frac{1}{3} }
\end{align*}
I cannot seem to get my answer to check. Where did I go wrong?

Here is my second attempt to solve the problem:

To solve this equation, we reduce it to a linear differential equation with the substitution $v = y^3$.
\begin{align*}
xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + y^3 &= 1 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} &= 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
3xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 3y^3 &= 3 \\
x \frac{dv}{dx} + 3v &= 3 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} + 3 x^{-1} v &= 3x^{-1} \\
\end{align*}
Now we have a first order linear differential equation. To solve it, we use the integrating factor $I = e^{\int P(x)}$. In
this case, we have $P(x) = 3x^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
I &= e^{3 \int x^{-1} \, dx} = e ^ { 3 \ln{|x|}} \\
I &= 3x \\
3x \frac{dv}{dx} + 9 v &= 9 \\
\end{align*}
Now, I want to write:
$$ D( 3xv ) = 9 $$
but that is wrong. What did I do wrong?

Here is my third attempt to solve the problem. Last time, I made a mistake in finding the integrating factor.

To solve this equation, we reduce it to a linear differential equation with the substitution $v = y^3$.
\begin{align*}
xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + y^3 &= 1 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} &= 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} \\
3xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 3y^3 &= 3 \\
x \frac{dv}{dx} + 3v &= 3 \\
\frac{dv}{dx} + 3 x^{-1} v &= 3x^{-1} \\
\end{align*}
Now we have a first order linear differential equation. To solve it, we use the integrating factor $I = e^{\int P(x)}$. In
this case, we have $P(x) = 3x^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
I &= e^{3 \int x^{-1} \, dx} = e ^ { 3 \ln{|x|}} \\
I &= x^3 \\
x^3 \frac{dv}{dx} + 3 x^2 v &= 3x^2 \\
D( x^3v ) &= x^3 + C \\
x^3v &= x^3 + C \\
v &= Cx^{-3} + 1 \\
y^3 &= Cx^{-3} + 1
\end{align*}

Do I have it right now?

Comment: $e^{3\log x}\ne 3x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xy^2y'+y^3=1$$ or with $u:=y^3$, $$xu'+3u=3.$$

We have the particular solution $u_p=1$, and the homogeneous equation is separable, giving

$$u_h=cx^{-3}.$$

Finally,

$$y=\sqrt[3]{cx^{-3}+1}.$$

---

Check:

$$xy'+y=x\frac{-3cx^{-4}}{3(cx^{-3}+1)^{2/3}}+\sqrt[3]{cx^{-3}+1}=\frac{-3cx^{-3}+3x^{-3}+1}{(cx^{-3}+1)^{2/3}}=\frac1{y^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xy'+y=y^{-2} \implies \frac{dy}{y^{-2}-y}=\frac{dx}{x} \implies \int \frac{-1}{3}\frac{-3y^2dy}{1-y^3}=\int \frac{dx}{x}+\ln C$$
$$\implies \frac{-1}{3} \ln (1-y^3)=\ln cx \implies y=\left( 1-\frac{1}{c^3x^3} \right)^{1/3}$$